# How can I make the bootloader recognizes Windows System partition?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows

I have two SSD of equal size, one NVME the other regular SSD.

I had `Windows 10` on the fast one (Recovery and System partitions) while Windows Data partition and Ubuntu partition was on the second slower SSD.

I had a problem that caused my `Ubuntu 18.04` kernel to stop working so I had to reinstall Ubuntu.

Since I use Ubuntu much more frequently than Windows I decided that Ubuntu should be in the faster SSD instead.

I copy pasted the Windows System partition over to the slower SSD and I installed Ubuntu in a small partition in the faster SSD.

I had also deleted the Windows Recovery partition.

The current partitioning looks like this:

## On the faster SSD

The first partition is the boot partition.
The second partition is the old Windows System partition.
The third partition is the new Ubuntu 19.10 partition

What I am planning to do is to grow the Ubuntu partition. Maybe I should also have 3 partitions, a root /, a home partition and a swap partition. If that's a good way please let me know.
[image: NVME partitions]

## On the slower SSD

The first partition is the copied Windows System partition.
The second partition is unallocated
The third partition is the Windows Data partition (has always been there)
[image: Slower SSD partitions]

### Questions

- How can I make the bootloader recognizes Windows on the second SSD?
- How can I restore the Recovery partition I deleted?
- Is it safe to grow the Ubuntu partition directly?
- Is it possible to re-partition the Ubuntu into root, home and swap partition? And is such change worth it?

Comment: 1. Suggest you try a Windows forum regarding getting that to boot again. 2. Unless you made a backup of the recovery partition it looks like you have overwritten the original so you probably cannot restore it. 3. You need to boot a live environment and run GParted from there to expand your Ubuntu partition. 4. You can repartition as described however you don’t need a swap partition. 19.10 uses a swap file by default. You can argue separate / and home partitions has advantages. I’ve used both approaches at different times and cannot say there is much difference.

Comment: Separate / and home partitions are slightly easier for situations where you need to reinstall. A single partition means you don’t need to guess how to share out the available disk space. With the former you can run out of space on one partition when there’s plenty left on the other.